# Как найти среднее направление ветра

Tags: математика, статистика

Каждую минуту приходят показания от датчика ветра. Необходимо рассчитать среднее направление ветра за последние 10 минут. 
Первым делом применил функцию AVG ко всем 10 записям, но быстро понял что с направлением такой способ усреднения не работает.

На данный момент имеется такая функция:

```
def get_avg_direction (directions):
      sinSum = 0
      cosSum = 0
      for value in directions:
        sinSum += math.sin(math.radians(value))
        cosSum += math.cos(math.radians(value))

      return ((math.degrees(math.atan2(sinSum, cosSum)) + 360) % 360)
```

Насколько она верна?

Comment: По-хорошему к направлению нужно еще и значение. Я бы суммировал ветер **как вектора**, и смотрел, куда направлен результирующий вектор.

Comment: Датчик выдает два числа: направление в градусах и скорость. Среднюю скорость я нахожу отдельно стандартным суммированием и делением.

Comment: Вот и вычисляйте проекции на ось x и на ось y и суммируйте. Так сказать, взвешенное вычисление синусов и косинусов.

Comment: Найдите средний угол в градусах. Это и будет среднее направление.

Comment: @becouse, в половине дней месяца ветер дул на север (0 градусов), в половине - на юг (180 градусов). Складываем, делим, получаем в среднем 90 градусов, т.е. в среднем ветер дул на восток. Вы считаете, что это правильно?

Comment: @insolor среднее значение не имеет семантики само по себе. С математической точки зрения будет 90 градусов как среднее в ряду чисел. В ответе, кстати, правильно указано, что надо работать с векторами, а не отдельно с углом и модулем.

Comment: @becouse, так и вопрос был не про среднее значение вообще, а про среднее значение угла. Советовать в этом просто брать средний угол - неправильно.

Comment: @insolor среднее значение угла будет как раз 90 градусов по вашему примеру. А вот среднее значение вектора считается совсем по другому. Автор решил разделить вектор на компоненты, и найти по каждой среднее. Вот и получилась путаница.

Comment: @becouse Так 90 или 270?...

Comment: @Mikhailo Здесь среднее значение нужно считать для вектора, а не для угла. Среднее значение периодической величины в общем случае не определено.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Судя по функции, ваш язык - Python.

Вам для ответа потребуется не только массив направлений, но и массив скоростей (то есть направления векторов ветра и длины этих векторов). Предполагается, что эти массивы одинаковой длины.

Вот исправленный код на основе вашей функции с примером использования функции:

```
import math

def get_avg_direction (directions, speeds):
    sinSum = 0.0
    cosSum = 0.0
    for value, speed in zip(directions, speeds):
        sinSum += speed * math.sin(math.radians(value))
        cosSum += speed * math.cos(math.radians(value))
    sinSum = sinSum / len(directions)
    cosSum = cosSum / len(directions)
    return ((math.degrees(math.atan2(sinSum, cosSum)) + 360) % 360), math.sqrt(cosSum*cosSum + sinSum*sinSum)

d, sp = get_avg_direction([90, 90, 270], [1, 1, 4])

print d, sp
```

Comment: Среднее направление требует суммировать нормированные вектора. Сравните "направление среднего ветра" и "среднее направление ветра". Вы сосчитали первую величину. Кажется автору нужна вторая.

Answer (score -1):

Если говорить в терминах обработки сигналов, то вы имеете 10 комплексных отсчётов в показательной форме, то есть амплитуда + фаза. Переведите их из показательной в алгебраическую, просуммируйте и фаза этой суммы даст вам нужный результат.

Думаю в питоне есть всё необходимо для комплексной арифметики

Comment: Судя по духу заданного вопроса, автору рановато говорить о комплексных числах, тем более что тут они как раз, о чём в пословице - "из пушки по воробьям". Автору попросту нужно взять среднее векторов, и всего-то.

Comment: комплексное число и есть вектор, но для которого есть библиотеки, и в C++ и в питоне

Comment: Так то да, но всё равно это излишнее усложнение, если уж автор вопроса модули векторов усредняет, то про комплексные числа я бы не стал пока говорить...